# What happens when lightweight transaction and normal insert were executed at the same time?

Tags: cassandra

I've read the Cassandra article about [lightweight-transaction](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/lightweight-transactions-in-cassandra-2-0), and I think I've understood how the Paxos works.

I understood that with Paxos, CAS (compare-and-set) get linearized; the Paxos algorithm is used to determine which CAS is accepted. (CAS operation is used as a "value" of Paxos algorithm)

My question is, what happens if the INSERT lightweight-transaction and normal INSERT statement were executed for a same primary key?

In my understanding, normal INSERT operation does not utilize the facilities of Paxos, and thus if used along with LWT, something not desired would happen.

Am I correct? If so, what would happen? If not, how is the normal INSERT gets handled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using both regular inserts and CAS operations for the same table is not recommended. Chances are that regular inserts will be executed out of order, which is what you're trying to prevent using paxos.

The same is even true for reads. Any reads on tables that are updated using CAS must use `SERIAL` consistency level to make sure that you always see the result of the last CAS operation. Using `SERIAL` will coordinate query execution using paxos together with any updates and thus prevents out of order execution.

Comment: May I ask if there's any source document I can refer to?

Comment: E.g. "CAS operations" section in http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-error-handling-done-right